# Example of finitely generated and flat $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of characteristic $p$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

Fix a prime $p$. Let $\mathbb Z_p$ be ring of $p$-adic integers.

> What are the examples of finitely generated and flat $\mathbb Z_p$-algebra of characterisc $p$?

> What are the examples of Noetherian and flat $\mathbb Z_p$-algebra of characteristic $p$ ?

---

there is a canonical homomorphism $\mathbb Z_p \to \mathbb Z_p/p \mathbb Z_p:=\mathbb F_p$. So $\mathbb F_p$ is $\mathbb Z_p$-algebra. It is finitely generated. But $\mathbb F_p$ does not seem flat $\mathbb Z_p$-algebra. Similarly $\mathbb F_p[x_1, \cdots, x_n],~\mathbb F_p[[x_1, \cdots, x_n]]$ are also finitely generated $\mathbb Z_p$-algebra. But none of them seems flat as $\mathbb Z_p$-algebra. The same is true for the 2nd question as well, i.e., $\mathbb F_p, ~\mathbb F_p[x_1, \cdots, x_n],~\mathbb F_p[[x_1,\cdots,x_n]]$ are all Noetherian $\mathbb Z_p$-algebra but doesn't seem flat.

> Are there examples of the above two questions ?

Thanks

Comment: $A$ can't be a flat $\Bbb{Z}_p$-module if it is of characteristic $p$, tensor with $A$ the multiplication by $p$ map $\Bbb{Z}_p \to \Bbb{Z}_p $.

Comment: @reuns, thanks. Can you show the calculation ? suppose we have the exact sequence $0 \to \mathbb Z_p \overset{p \maps p \mathbb Z_p}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb Z_p \to \mathbb Z_p/p \mathbb Z_p \to 0$. So tensoring with char. $p$ ring $A$, we have $0 \to \mathbb A \otimes_{\mathbb Z_p}Z_p \overset{p \mapsto  p \mathbb Z_p}{\longrightarrow} A \otimes_{\mathbb Z_p} \mathbb Z_p \to A \otimes_{\mathbb Z_p} \mathbb Z_p/p \mathbb Z_p \to 0$. How to show the 2nd sequence is not exact ?

Comment: The second arrow is the $0$ map

Comment: @reuns, so $A \otimes_{\mathbb Z_p} \mathbb Z_p/p \mathbb Z_p=0$, since $A$ is of characteristic $p$. Is it ?

Comment: ?? I'm saying that the multiplication by $p$ sends everything to $0$ as $A\otimes \Bbb{Z}_p$ is also of characteristic $p$.

Comment: @reuns, thanks. So the final question. Can $A$ be flat $\mathbb Z_p/p \mathbb Z_p$-module, where $A$ are in my examples above ? At least $\mathbb F_p$ is flat $\mathbb F_p$-module. what about $A=\mathbb F_p[x]$ or $A=\mathbb F_p[[x]]$ ? Are these flat $\mathbb F_p$-module ?

Comment: Aren't $k$-vector spaces always free and flat $k$-modules